# Rewrite syntax in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just know how htaccess works but I am always confused with the writing syntax and I appreciate if anyone could help me solving the below htaccess issue.

I have couple pages linking to redirect to something like

```
http://mydomain.com.au/product-details.php/142/categoryAbstract
```

but due to the mistakes of previous developer the images are not loading unless that url is

```
http://mydomain.com.au/product-details.html/142/categoryAbstract
```

He converted all php pages to html (I really don't know what's this intention in doing that) but

now the url should work even if it as http://mydomain.com.au/product-details.php/142/categoryAbstract

He used the below htaccess for this but its not working. If I manually change the url from `.php` to `.html` everything working fine.

```
RewriteRule ^product-details.html/(.*)/(.*)$    product-details.php?productid=$1&category=$2
```

I need a working line of code so that even the url `http://mydomain.com.au/product-details.php/142/categoryAbstract` should work.

Comment: Did the previous developer actually convert all pages to HTML, or did he create a line in the htaccess file that changes the extension? Can you look in your htaccess file and see if such a line exists?

Comment: He just wrote a line as that even if he calling phpinfo.html in browser its just running.

Answer (score 2):

You will just need an `OR` group `(a|b)` to account for both possibilities:

```
RewriteRule ^product-details\.(html|php)/(.*)/(.*)$    product-details.php?productid=$1&category=$2 
#---------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That can be improved a little though.  The `(.*)` are greedy matches.  You are better served to use `([^/]+)` as the first grouping to match everything up to the next `/`. I have also escaped the dot as `\.` so it is matched as a literal instead of *any character*.

```
RewriteRule ^product-details\.(html|php)/([^/]+)/(.*)$    product-details.php?productid=$1&category=$2
```

The `.php` extension is commonly modified either through rewriting or actual file renaming and server configuration to parse `.html` as `.php` in order to hide some server-side information from end users.  To prevent them from knowing what technologies the site runs on the back end.  It less common to actually rename files to `.html` than to use URL rewriting to hide the `.php`, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^product-details.html/(.*)/(.*)$ product-details.php?productid=$1&category=$2
```

What this rule does is take everything after `product-details.html/` and before the last / and a second bit gets taken after the last / until the end of the line. then it takes those bits and puts them where the $1 and $2 are.

to change it so it accepts .html and .php you can change it with

```
RewriteRule ^product-details(.html|.php)/(.*)/(.*)$ product-details.php?productid=$2&category=$3
```

Because it looks like the first bit you are grabbing are numbers and `(.*)` is a greedy selector it may be better to replace it with ([0-9]*) which will only select numbers. that way if you ever have /s in your catagory you'll be fine. giving you:

```
RewriteRule ^product-details(.html|.php)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ product-details.php?productid=$2&category=$3
```